# Controlling how deep a reflection goes in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

If I want a reflection on a glossy surface to fade out after only a bit, how can I do that in Cycles? I have tried using a texture to regulate where to have a glossy shader and where to have a diffuse one. This however, doesn't work as the object casting the reflection is circular so a straight border as I get when using textures doesn't work.